# Which Star Trek episodes deal with the Omega Particle?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-enterprise

I'm interested in learning more about the Omega Particle as revealed in the Star Trek TV shows (TNG, DS9, VOY, ENT).  What shows deal with the Omega Particle, and what is the recommended viewing order?

I would like to create an "Omega Particle play list" in Netflix/Prime and binge watch. It would be great if you can include season/episode numbers so that they are easier to navigate to for watching.

Comment: http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Omega_molecule

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first episode to mention and deal with the Omega particle was Star Trek: Voyager S4 E21 [The Omega Directive](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Omega_Directive_%28episode%29). No subsequent movies or shows deal with it, but S7 E19 [Q2](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Q2_%28episode%29) mentions it in passing. No additional information there.

In non-canon sources, Star Trek: Online uses it as a plot point for the Dyson Spheres and Iconian Gateways.

Comment: Good point, but only in passing... I'll update my answer though.

Comment: I thought I remember the Omega particle being a plot point in an ENT episode?

Comment: @iMerchant If it was, [Memory Alpha](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Omega_molecule) failed to mention it.

Comment: @iMerchant I don't recall anything of the sort either.  If you have a scene in mind though, you might be mixing it up with something else...

Comment: @Izkata - I thought I recall reading something on here about Archer going back/forward in time and nuking the Omega particle in fluidic space to kill the Borg. Or something like that. Maybe I'm dreaming this all up or going crazy or maybe it was in a book. I don't know.

Comment: @iMerchant Archer did time travel a few times, but that all involved the Temporal Cold War, which [was in 13 episodes](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Temporal_Cold_War#Appearances).  Fluidic space [was only entered once, in VOY](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Scorpion_(episode)) - and the Borg were temporary allies who brought Voyager there.  But the ENT Enterprise [did face off against the Borg once](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Regeneration_(episode)).

Comment: @iMerchant But yes, it is entirely possible it was in a novel.  I don't know much about them (and haven't read any), but do remember there being more time travel, crossovers, etc.

Comment: @iMerchant: "Archer going back/forward in time and nuking the Omega particle in fluidic space to kill the Borg" - sounds like over-the-top fan fiction to me.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: “sounds like over-the-top fan fiction to me” — of course, so does a lot of *Enterprise*.